# Squid proxy server with multiple IP automatically changes the outgoing address

Tags: linux, proxy, server, squid

I have a squid proxy server with 10 public IP addresses, I am using it precisely for the purpose of outgoing address. I want this multiple IP addresses to be randomly elected and changed every 2 minutes when the requests go out of the server. is that possible? how to do it in a server side, and what exactly we need to do in the client side?

Regards